# Is it possible to join servers that are already in a database mirroring session into an Active Directory domain?

Tags: sql-server, mirroring, active-directory

We have created a SQL Server database mirroring session on two workgroup servers(not in any domain). Now we are asked to join those two servers into a domain. Is this possible without rebuild the whole mirroring architecture?